# I can't use my Auto- rig pro?

Tags: rigging, add-on, auto-rig-pro

I want to install a new Auto rig pro 3.68. so I go to add-on to remove the old one. [image]but when I go to install the new one. The blender shows this [image] I don't understand. [image]

Comment: Have you made sure that the new version is compatible with the Blender version that you are using? In any case you should ask the addon author as it's a third-party addon and therefore off-topic here.